# When to upgrade/install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: upgrade

I am using Ubuntu 13.10, and looking forward for the launch of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Please suggest me how should I upgrade to 14.04 LTS?

Comment: When it is released on April 17th, or wait a bit to avoid the big rush on the servers (and any emergent bugs).

Comment: Is there some compelling reason to upgrade (bug fix, some "must have software?) ? How much do you enjoy stability ? If you enjoy a stable system, and hav The patient denies the use of alcohol.  reason to upgrade, wait 1 month after the release. This will allow most of the major bugs to be identified and resolved.

Comment: Ubuntu 13.10 is supported until October so you can upgrade any time between April 17 and end of life in October. Make sure you back-up before you upgrade in case anything goes wrong.  You will be able to upgrade via the Update manager.  Personally I'd wait a few weeks/months so any initial bugs have time to be found and fixed but it's up to you.

Comment: @ bodhi.zazen I had no problem with 12.04.4 LTS. After clean install of 13.10 I faced two yet-to-resolve issues. 1. My computer can be shut down, but it automatically boots again. 2. Google Earth is opening and crashing immediately thereafter. So, I was wondering if all these would be resolved in 14.04 LTS. No other compelling issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### I have been running both **12.04 LTS** and **13.10** for some time.

The recent Ubuntu versions (12.10, 13.04, and 13.10) have not always been stable (graphics drivers, obscure USB devices, CD/DVD playback, etc.). *There have generally been no such issues with **Ubuntu 12.04 LTS**.*

Initial testing (last 10 days) suggest that (apart from a few glitches on new features) this upcoming release will be as good as **12.04 LTS**.

### ***Wait three more weeks, and then migrate (or do a fresh install).***

Comment: I have installed 13.10 through DVD. Then after few days the CD/DVD RW drive gradually stopped working. First it stopped writing. Then reading. Now it works at times to read only mode. System testing reports about a READ/WRITE error. Does this mean that the CD/DVD drive has gone bad? Or is this a problem related to the use of Ubuntu 13.10?

Comment: No, issue related to **13.10** was playing *some* DVD content (DVD menus, movie playback, codecs, etc.). *If your optical (CD/DVD) drive is not working it may be the drive.*

Answer (score 0):

The proper way is to set the option of upgrading to new releases in your software settings.

Open the Software Centre and go to the Edit menu. Click 'software sources' and then the 'updates' tab. Set 'Notify me of a new Ubuntu version' to 'For any new version' and, with luck, your upgrade will go ok as part of normal updates.

Here's some advise on upgrading from Ubuntu :

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Upgrades

It is probably wise to download 14.04 onto a dvd or usb before you attempt the upgrade, just in case you need to do a fresh install. So, like the page says, make sure you back up any valuable data.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I found all you have mentioned in "Software and Updates" and not in "Ubuntu Software Center".

Comment: There's always more than one way to skin the cat with Ubuntu!